# basic list comprehension with else if conditions for printing values from two dictionary

Tags: python, list-comprehension

it is required to convert alphabets to numbers. So, i used dictionary to carry out the task, but now, having problem with list comprehension.

the text has both capital and small alphabets, so i created two dictionary, one for small and other for caps.
now, i want to create a list which will be comprehended from these two dictionary based on the values found in the text.

```
x = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
y = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
data = dict(zip(x, range(1,27)))
data1 = dict(zip(y, range(1,27)))
t = "Learning python."
q = [data[i] if i in data else data1[i] for i in t]
print(" ".join(map(str, q)))
```

expected result : 12 5 1 18 14 9 14 7 16 25 20 8 15 14

actual result:

```
File "C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXX.py", line 6, in <module>

    q = [data[i] if i in data else data1[i] for i in t ]

File "C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXX.py", line 6, in <listcomp>

    q = [data[i] if i in data else data1[i] for i in t ]

KeyError: ' '
```

Comment: Space is not in data or in data1

Comment: Look up `ord()`

Comment: ... also dot (`.`).

Comment: @hansolo i tried data.get(c, ''), it is also considering spaces,, so I am getting below result:
12 5 1 18 14 9 14 7  16 25 20 8 15 14
as we can see, between 7 and 16, space is present can it be done without spaces?

Comment: yes, spaces and "." are not in data.
when i tried like 
`
q = [data[i] for i in t if i in data]
`
it gave me the result but "L(15)" was missing, so to include it, i had to include a new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the comments already mentioned, your translation dicts do not contain spaces `' '` and dots `'.'`; therefore you will run into a `KeyError`.

a different way is this:

noting that

```
ord('a') = 97
ord('z') = 122
```

you could use `bytes`:

```
t = "Learning python."
res = [i - 96 for i in t.lower().encode() if 97 <= i <= 122]
print(res) # [12, 5, 1, 18, 14, 9, 14, 7, 16, 25, 20, 8, 15, 14]
```

using `t.lower()` i perform the translation to all lower case, then i `.encode()` that to a `bytes` object (which behaves like a sequence of integers) and select the ones in the printable range.

---

also note that if you really need to translate stuff in a string, i suggest you use [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
table = str.maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 
                      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
t = "Learning python."
print(t.translate(table))
# LEARNING PYTHON.
```

Comment: yes, one of the clever approach, no need to create a dictionary.. (y)
thnx... :)

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh to be fair: at first i misunderstood the question and posted something stupid. that was downvoted. but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just do,

```
>>> x = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> y = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> data = dict(zip(x, range(1,27)))
>>> data1 = dict(zip(y, range(1,27)))
>>> t = "Learning python."
>>> [data.get(c, data1.get(c)) for c in t if data.get(c, data1.get(c))] # assuming you don't want the values that are not in the `dict`s
[12, 5, 1, 18, 14, 9, 14, 7, 16, 25, 20, 8, 15, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

Must easier if you using numpy

```
import numpy as np

x = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz .'
# x = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'  # still OK
np_x = np.array(list(x))

t = "Learning python."
np_t = np.array(list(t.lower()))
result = list(np.where(np_t.reshape(np_t.size, 1) == np_x)[1] + 1)
# [12,  5,  1, 18, 14,  9, 14,  7, 27, 16, 25, 20,  8, 15, 14, 28]
```

Note that the above code still work in case of `x` doesn't included `space` or `dot`

Answer (score 0):

Simpler:

```
s = "Learning python."
alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
print(*[str(alpha.index(i)+1) if i in alpha else "" for i in s.lower()])
```

Output:

```
12 5 1 18 14 9 14 7  16 25 20 8 15 14
```